# Zend_Form require => true error

Tags: zend-form

I have a problem with Zend_Form empty validator, it validates and return true even if the form is empty. For exemple if username = ' ' the validator returns true.

The Form

```
$this->addElement('text','username',array(
        'label'         => 'APP_FORM_USERNAME',
        'require'       => true,
        'validators'    => array(
            array('validator' => 'StringLength', true, 'options' => array(3, 50)),
            array('validator' => 'Alpha', true),
            array('validator' => 'NotEmpty', true, 'options' =>      Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::ALL)
        ),
        'filters'       => array(
            'StringTrim'
        ))
    );
```

How can i return false if is a string is empty?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer even though I think you probably have found an answer since you ased this question a couple of months ago already.

`setRequired(true)` has actually the same effect than the `notEmpty` validator. It will add a `notEmpty`validator on top of the validators stack.

Your mistake is just a simple syntax error: *require* should be **required**.